# Get text with line number from xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

Can you please tell me how to get line number and text from xml file?

for example...

```
var varLines = xmldocument.ToString().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Here, I got line numbers but how to get text as per line number

```
1.<p>This article contends that a new concept of education
2.</p>
2.<contrib-group>
3.<contrib>Organization, Peabody College of Vanderbil University, 230 Appleton Place,</contrib>
4.@</contrib-group>
5.<day></day>
6.<fpage>3</fpage>
```

I want to have the ouptut as shown below:

```
1.<p>This article contends that a new concept of education
3.<contrib>Organization, Peabody College of Vanderbil University, 230 Appleton Place,</contrib>
4.@</contrib-group>
6.<fpage>3</fpage>
```

Please tell me how to get it

Comment: What kind of object is `xmldocument`?  Does the file you're reading have the numbers in it?  Are you reading it as XML or as something else?  Are you reading from a file at all?  Please provide a MCVE.(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know, if I understand your question right. 
First of all xml doesn´t work with line numbers, but with elements/attributes and content. To get specific elements you could jut use the XmlReader and go to each element you like to read it´s content or it´s name. 
See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720458%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: sir i need line numbers which tag contains text content

Comment: Hmm´, still don´t get your question, where do you think you get those line numbers from? XML does not have line numbers. You could

Comment: so can you please tell me another solution..Is it possible to get only text from string array except tag through regular expression

Comment: How do you "open" your xml file?

Comment: Could you show your Output right now when iterating over your array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First split your text as follows:

```
string[] lines = xmldocument.ToString().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then you need to extract the content.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>(); //Here we save the Values according to your line numbers
```

NOTE: The list will start at Index 0 while your lines start at 1 => +1 when extracting!!!

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<(.*)?>(.*?)</(.*?)");
Match match = regex.Match(line);
values.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
//Do this inside a foreach-loop for each line.

Output:
values[0]: This article contends that a new concept of education
```

Comment: @Bauss since this is not a real valid xml - xmls have never line numbers it is doing the job the questionowner asked for. For sure it would be a way better solution to remove the linenumbers and read the xml with and `XmlReader`and parse it. Since he explicit asked for an extraction from a string this answers the question: "so can you please tell me another solution..Is it possible to get only text from string array except tag through regular expression"

Comment: is it possible to extract only text in tag through Regular expression?

Comment: sure it is but as mentioned when working with xml structure it is always better to parse it into a class.... Generally you can extract everything with regex @ritz

Comment: hi sir,i have some query can it possible to get only text from tags which contains text ?

Comment: sure you can see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/939/An-Introduction-to-Regular-Expressions for a first look on regex.