# Get line number which tag contains text in XML file

Tags: c#

Can you please tell me how to get line number using XDocument or XmlDocument?

In XDocument,

Input:

```
1. <title-group>
2. <article-title>Education Finance: How It Differs from the and the 
Analytic and Data Collection    Changes It Implies</article-title>
4. </title-group>
5. <contrib-group>
6. <contrib contrib-type="author"><name><surname>Guthrie</surname><given-names>James W.</given-names></name><aff>Department of Leadership, Policy and Organization, Peabody College of Vanderbil University, 230 Appleton Place, @ Nashville, TN 37203-5721, E-mail: <email xlink="jwgxiii@sbcglobal.net">jwgxiii@sbcglobal.net</email></aff>
7. testest</contrib>
8. </contrib-group>
```

My output will look like:

```
2. <article-title>Education Finance: How It Differs from the and the Analytic and Data Collection    Changes It Implies</article-title>
6. <contrib contrib-type="author"><name><surname>Guthrie</surname><given-names>James W.</given-names></name><aff>Department of Leadership, Policy and Organization, Peabody College of Vanderbil University, 230 Appleton Place, @ Nashville, TN 37203-5721, E-mail: <email xlink="jwgxiii@sbcglobal.net">jwgxiii@sbcglobal.net</email></aff>
7. testest</contrib>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code, which reads your xml data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get line number for XElement here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471001/get-line-number-for-xelement-here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text with line number from xml file in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306857/get-text-with-line-number-from-xml-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [check using the `HasLineInfo` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  if the `XDocument` supports line information.
If it does you can use it via the [`IXmlLineInfo` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for functions like the [`LineNumber` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo.linenumber%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).